# ¿Por qué la velocidad de una query en SQL Server cambia tanto dependiendo de como se escriba una condición en el WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, vistas, eficiencia

Tengo cierta vista en `sqlserver` que almacena datos diarios con un campo fecha incluido (supongamos vista llamada vista_1). 
Adicional mente tengo una tabla `x` que me entrega la fecha para el día de ayer, mediante una query simple `(select distinct dia from tabla_x)`

El problema es que cuando intento obtener datos de la vista poniendo en la clausula `where` la query de la fecha, la consulta demora demasiado tiempo. Abajo pongo mas o menos como escribo la consulta

```
Select * from vista_1 where fecha=(select distinct dia from tabla_x)
```

Lo raro del tema es que si la fecha la pongo literal, es decir, si la escribo como por ejemplo '20170101' la query no demora nada. abajo el Ejemplo

```
Select * from vista_1 where fecha='20170101'
```

¿Qué debo hacer para acelerar mi primera consulta? o para crear un método alternativo para acelerar la `query` dada. Obviamente asumo que agregar una consulta en la clausula `where` trae consigo una ineficiencia, pero la diferencia entre ambas opciones es demasiada a mi entender

Comment: en la primera consulta estas haciendo dos queries en la segunda solo una

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el explain en tu pregunta? Encontrarás el botón para [edit] al pie de la misma.

Comment: Si agregas el explain, podremos generar una respuesta mas justa a tu problema.

Comment: trata de indexar las tablas que vas a usar, trata de usar timestamp o date time, prueba con diferentes tipos de busqueda con where, como join, left join, right loin etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que estas teniendo viene dado por la forma en que la base resuelve la consulta.

Sin ver el explain plan, que eliminaría la mayor parte de tus dudas, supongo que tu vista, no esta accediendo por ningún indice, o tiene muchos registros, o el distinct le esta costando mucho.

Si tu segunda query es una vista común, entonces el optimizador de consultas puede reescribir la consulta como quiera, haciendo que algo que parezca que va a andar mas rápido, todavía ande mucho mas lento. Ademas las vistas se optimizan para determinados parámetros, y a veces para otros querys esto resulta costoso

No hay una forma canónica de acelerar la consulta. La misma depende de las tablas que estés usando y sus indices.

Si queres mas información, deberías leer el explain plan, y ver que esta haciendo tu base de datos para ejecutar la consulta.

A simple vista, la primera accede a dos tablas, y la segunda solo a una, con lo cual eso ya la haría mas rápida.

Comment: ademas de que esta haciendo un distinct y esta es una formula por lo cual se demora

Comment: si, esta aclarado en el segundo parrafo

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, el problema radica es que son tablas que no puedo modificar solo acceder mediante select. De todas maneras me ayudaron mucho sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

sin el plan de ejecucion no se te puede ayudar mucho, prueba con el siguiente cambio

```
Declare @Dia datetime
select distinct @dia = dia from tabla_x
Select * from vista_1 where fecha=@dia
```